# Form to email script for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, forms, cdonts

Cdonts used to be the de facto form to email script, I think for classic ASP. Does someone know of a better form to email script I could use for asp.net please?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Can you explain a little further please?

You are using asp.net (forms) and you want to fill in a form and then use the parameters from the form to send an email ? Am I right ?

Comment: Hi Neal. Yes that's what I'd like. What FormMail is for PHP, I'd like for asp.net. :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely get the original question but all you want to know about ASP.NET mailing can be found here: http://www.systemnetmail.com/.

Comment: Thanks XIII. I am not asp.net guru and all I need to do is send a form from a flash form, hits the form to email script which then sends the email to the client. CDONTS was easy to set up in it's day, but I need something that's as easy for the .net platform. I will have a look into this and send it onto our developer. Just thought there was something easier. ;)

Comment: .NET itself has everything in it. It might look a bit different than classic ASP, developed in that myself in the past, but it's all there.